# How to fetch user using the TrueVault API

Tags: truevault

I'm trying to fetch a user from the TrueVault API using curl.

I've been using the following curl command (as per the documentation):

```
curl https://api.truevault.com/v2/users/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx7ce \
    -X GET \
    -u API_KEY:"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx461"
```

The credentials:

```
user_id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx7ce
api key: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx461
```

Every time I send the request I'm getting an error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "AUTH.UNSUCCESSFUL",
    "message": "Authentication Failure.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
},
"result": "error",
"transaction_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3ba883e31f99"
```

So I wanted to check if maybe I'm doing wrong or might be something else.

This user has all permissions (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Auth Header is malformed. You can read more about how to build the Auth Header here: https://docs.truevault.com/overview#authentication.

For a simple curl you can use the `-u` option instead of building the base64 Basic Auth header. `-u` expects `username:password`, but TrueVault's API is token-based so they want you to do "$API_KEY:". *Note* the empty second component! That trailing `:` is critical.

Try this:

```
curl https://api.truevault.com/v2/users/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx7ce \
    -X GET \
    -u "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx461:"
```

Comment: Now, if I were to do the same request via Postman, how would I do it?, because I've been trying to fill the fields in accordance to the curl, but no luck. Sorry for the newbie question.